# Problema para "Salvar imagem como" php

Tags: php, html, gd

Tenho um código que gera uma assinatura eletrônica porém quando o usuário clica com o botão direito na imagem gerada para "Salvar imagem como" o nome da imagem vem como padrão o **nome_da_pagina.php.png**.

Como eu faço pra tirar o `.php` do nome do arquivo a ser salvo?

Pois os usuários leigos não estão sabendo renomear o nome do arquivo pra tirar a extensão **.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");

$image = imagecreatefrompng("assinatura.png");
$imageCel = imagecreatefrompng("cel.png");
$imageWhats = imagecreatefrompng("whats.png");
$imgPira = imagecreatefrompng("piracicaba.png");
$imgBotucatu = imagecreatefrompng("botucatu.png");
$imgLencois = imagecreatefrompng("lencois.png");
$imgJau = imagecreatefrompng("jau.png");

if (!empty ($_POST["name"])) {
    $fotinha = $_POST["name"];
    $imgFotinha = imagecreatefrompng("upload/".$fotinha.".png");
}

$tileColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 63, 114);
$gray = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 100, 100);

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$funcao = $_POST["funcao"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$cel = $_POST["cel"];

if (!empty($_POST["cel"])) {
    imagecopy($image, $imageCel, 445, 17, 0, 0, 12, 16);
    imagettftext($image, 10, 0, 460, 30, $tileColor, "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assinatura\\fonts\\Helvetica\\Helvetica-Normal.ttf", $cel);
    if (isset($_POST["whats"])) {
        imagecopy($image, $imageWhats, 560, 17, 0, 0, 15, 16);
    }
}

if (!empty ($_POST["name"])) {
    imagecopy($image, $imgFotinha, 10, 16, 0, 0, 100, 100);
}

imagettftext($image, 12, 0, 110, 33, $tileColor, "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assinatura\\fonts\\Helvetica\\Helvetica Bold.ttf", $nome);
imagettftext($image, 10, 0, 120, 50, $tileColor, "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assinatura\\fonts\\Helvetica\\Helvetica-Normal.ttf", $funcao);

imagettftext($image, 10, 0, 332, 30, $tileColor, "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assinatura\\fonts\\Helvetica\\Helvetica-Normal.ttf", $telefone);
imagettftext($image, 11, 0, 334, 56, $tileColor, "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assinatura\\fonts\\Helvetica\\Helvetica-Normal.ttf", $email);

$filial = $_POST["filial"];

if ($filial == "piracicaba") {
    imagecopy($image, $imgPira, 310, 75, 0, 0, 324, 11);
}

if ($filial == "botucatu") {
    imagecopy($image, $imgBotucatu, 310, 75, 0, 0, 324, 11);
}

if ($filial == "lencois") {
    imagecopy($image, $imgLencois, 310, 75, 0, 0, 324, 11);
}

if ($filial == "jau") {
    imagecopy($image, $imgJau, 310, 75, 0, 0, 324, 11);
}

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);


?>
```

Comment: Isso acontece pois você está gerando uma imagem a partir de uma página php, você pode definir uma roa para uma imagem à parte ou fazer um botão **baixar imagem**

Comment: como posso fazer esta rota?

Comment: Esse é um exemplo simples de como fazer https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router . Tem formas mas completas e complexas, mas inicialmente isso deve resolver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta alterar o *header* *Content-disposition*.

**Cabeçalho**

De acordo com [RFC6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266), “o campo de cabeçalho *Content-Disposition* é usado para transmitir informações adicionais sobre como processar a carga útil da resposta e também pode ser usado para anexar metadados adicionais, como o nome do arquivo a ser usado ao salvar a carga útil da resposta localmente.”

Esse cabeçalho possui dois campos: *disposition-type* e *filename*.

**Disposition Type**

Se o tipo de disposição corresponder a "attachment", isso indica que o destinatário deve solicitar ao usuário que salve a resposta localmente, em vez de processá-la normalmente (conforme seu tipo de mídia).

Por outro lado, se corresponder a "inline", isso implica em processamento padrão.

**Filename**

Este campo fornece informações o nome do arquivo, que poderá ser baixado pelo usuário.

Caso o valor do campo *disposition-type* seja *inline*, o valor deste campo poderá ser utilizado na janela *Salvar como…*.

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="psr.png"');
```

Caso o valor do campo *disposition-type* seja *attachment*, o navegador poderá forçar o *download* do conteúdo conforme o *content-type* e o *filename* indicado nos cabeçalhos de resposta.

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="psr_f.png"');
```

Comment: perfeito. obrigado